# How to call SignalR hub when application start?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, hangfire

I have some recurring background jobs in my application using [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire):

```
public class NotificationWeeklyHub : Hub
{
        public void SendNotificationWeekly()
        {
            /*Recurring Job
              Clients.All.SendNotificationWeekly();
            */
            // code....
        }
}
```

So I want to send  notification for my users, in this case I want to call my Hub when application is started, So How can I call my hub in this way?
PS: My client side code for calling the hub:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var notifyWeekly = $.connection.notificationWeekly;
    notifyWeekly.client.sendNotificationWeekly = function () {
        toastr.success("Message");
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        notifyWeekly.server.sendNotificationWeekly();
    });
</script>
```

My goal is just sending notification (in my case using [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) library) in those particular times. Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: To perform startup tasks after application start use [Application_Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) event in your `global.asax` file

Comment: If your application is just starting, you won't have any clients connected.... so what would be the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like may do it:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // get the hub from the globalHost 
    IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationWeeklyHub>();

    // send the message to all clients, make sure that the method is camelCase.
    hubContext.Clients.All.sendNotificationWeekly("your message");
}
```

**EDIT:**

Now regarding your hub code, looks like your method is just to call the clients and since any public method in your hub will be available to the client you can clean your hub code and change it to be like follows:

```
public class NotificationWeeklyHub : Hub
{
}
```

Comment: So Here I should call `hubContext.Clients.All.sendNotificationWeekly("your message");` what about inside my hub method? Dose it necessary to define same call there? My Hub class should be empty class without hub method? right?

Comment: any public method in your hub will be available to the client, if this method is just to call the client then, yes your hub should be empty